# Problem with library of arduino in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino

I have already looked for the questions but I have not found anything, I have an arduino library that vscode fails to "find", this library is called "IRremote" and works very well on the arduino ide and on others, but here I am from problems and I feel for two days, the other libraries read them without problems, could you give me a help please?
Here place the code of the .json file
This is the library for download: http://downloads.arduino.cc/libraries/github.com/z3t0/IRremote-2.2.3.zip

Thanks so much

```
{
        "name": "Arduino",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "C:\\Users\\andre\\Desktop\\Program Instalattion\\Arduino\\tools\\**",
            "C:\\Users\\andre\\Desktop\\Program Instalattion\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\**",
            "C:\\Users\\andre\\Desktop\\Program Instalattion\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\**",
            "C:\\Users\\andre\\Desktop\\Program Instalattion\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino\\**",
            "C:\\Users\\andre\\Desktop\\PROG\\ITS FORNO\\Programma\\006\\ITS_FORNO\\**"
        ],
        "forcedInclude": [
            "C:\\Users\\andre\\Desktop\\Program Instalattion\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino\\Arduino.h"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "C:\\Users\\andre\\Desktop\\Program Instalattion\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr\\bin\\avr-gcc.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "defines": [
            "USBCON"
        ],
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "C:\\Users\\andre\\Desktop\\PROG\\ITS FORNO\\Programma\\006\\"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Libraries must be named lib.a so they can be found by the linker when it is supplied with command line option -l.